# Laptop turns on, OS not loading, black screen

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I have an old Fujtisu Amilo Pro V2065 laptop. About two months ago I plugged in a power adapter that turned out to be faulty (it was the original adapter for that laptop, but the cable was damaged and I didn't notice) and caused a short circuit. The laptop died and I was pretty sure I burned the motherboard, but when I tried a different, working adapter, the computer started fine, to my surprise. Yesterday I wanted to start it using a new adapter I've purchased, and got a nasty surprise - the machine starts, the fans spin, but then the screen goes blank. There's no evidence of anything happening - the HDD LED doesn't blink, so the OS most likely doesn't load. Hard reset didn't help. I've tried attaching an external display, but it just says "no signal".

I've searched around a bit and while there are a lot of questions about this issue, nobody actually hinted towards a faulty motherboard. This is why I'm asking: could that short-circuit actually cause this kind of damage? From my experience this should result in a fried motherboard, rendering the machine unable to start at all. I have some spare parts for that laptop, some old RAM sticks - should I give that a try?

Comment: It sounds like the power adapters you keep trying are either garbage or the completely wrong type.

Comment: The new power adapter is a genuine Fujitsu product, I've tried it with a second, similar laptop (same power requirements) and it works fine.

Comment: Do you get to the BIOS at all, or does the screen go blank before that?

Comment: Totally blank, absolutely nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short circuit often causes the RAM IC failure which consequently results in no boot and no video issue. Hence please check the the motherboard in service center and if this is the case replacing that particular IC will fix the issue.